# SharePoint Database "There is insufficient memory in resource pool 'internal to run this query"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

We are using SP2019 On-Premise with two-tier architecture, Application Tier and DB Tier. We just did a fresh installation with the basic configuration for SP services and applications and everything works fine on the Application server

However, the DB server is giving this error with regard to server memory:

> There is insufficient memory in resource pool 'internal to run this query

We executed the following queries:

- `sys.dm_os_process_memory`

[image]

- `sp_readerrorlog`

[image]

Our server specs is as follows:

- Windows Server 2019
- Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64) Sep 24 2019 13:48:23 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
- RAM: 128 GB, 120 GB allocated for SQL Server

I don't think that really SP needs more than the allocated RAM but I believe it is a configuration issue. Also, it might be a problem occurring from the running app services such as User Profiles and other SP default app services.

Comment: I don't know what that link is to but I'm not downloading it, and I doubt any/many others will; many of the users here are professionals and understand the dangers/foolishness of downloading a file from a stranger (on the internet). If the information is important to the question, include it in the question.

Comment: do you get errors on all queries? Or is it some specific ones?

Comment: Apparently SP related queries but I don't know which exact one

Comment: That's RTM of SQL Server 2019.  There have been _20_ cumulative updates shipped for that version.  Install the latest one and see if the problem goes away. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5024276-cumulative-update-20-for-sql-server-2019-4b282be9-b559-46ac-9b6a-badbd44785d2  SQL Server doesn't slipstream updates into the installer, so applying a CU after installation should be standard practice.

Comment: Setting max. server memory to 93.75% (120MB) seems much higher than the general recommendation of 75% (96MB). [Were you aware:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver16#recommendations): _The max server memory option only limits the size of the SQL Server buffer pool. The max server memory option does not limit a remaining unreserved memory area that SQL Server leaves for allocations of other components such as extended stored procedures, COM objects, non-shared DLLs and EXEs._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David mentioned, it was because of CU.

Although I installed multiple CUs after installation, the `KB5024276` seems to be the one solving the problem.

Thanks.